# Create windows installation media from Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04, ubuntu-mate

I recently broke my windows installation but I dual boot with Ubuntu

So now I need installation media

I tried just dd'ing the iso to my USB drive on /dev/sdb1 but it refused to boot inisisting I was trying to boot uefi in bios mode (even though my pc is set up to boot either)

I really need windows for college so how do I make install media without another windows install?

Comment: "even though my pc is set up to boot either" That is impossible. One method excludes the other method.  Your problem is not with Ubuntu and burning the ISO. it is with the boot method as you posted. If the system keeps "inisisting I was trying to boot uefi in bios mode"  you are booting incorrectly.

Comment: @Rinzwind no it has boot "priority". It's not mutually exclusive. It tries to boot Uefi, and then tries bios

Comment: @Rinzwind and besides, Ubuntu is installed as uefi so if that's the issue Ubuntu shouldn't boot. Tested both bios and uefi booting. There is no option to select one or the other in my settings, only which to try first

Comment: @Rinzwind it's a Lenovo ThinkPad T430s

Answer (score 1):

For creating a Windows install USB on a Linux machine check out [WoeUSB](https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB).
There's a prebuilt package in this [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Enilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt update
sudo apt install woeusb
```

Comment: I was looking for a solution that _didn't_ require building something from sources that I have to clone :-)

Comment: There's actually a prebuilt package in a PPA. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: BTW didn't result in boot able USB and made my hdd unbootable

Comment: @colbycdev woeusb is a popular and widely used tool and should be safe for normal operation. However, it might of course be possible that you can use it to overwrite your internal hdd instead of an external USB drive, if you pick the respective settings. I see nothing wrong with this answer, but you're free to elaborate what you did and how it might have broke things.

Comment: @ByteCommander I installed to my USB drive ofc. Had to do grub-install as per another answer. Now my hdd is screwed up bsd

Comment: *bad. Typo there